# Can I connect my VPN Gateway to Google VPC via VPC Peering? Or is there another way to do that?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vpc

I have a resource in my VPN that owns a static IP. From that resource I'd like to access one of my Cloud Run Services that lives *internal* in my GCP VPC network. I often stumble over the term "VPC Peering" and wonder if I can "tunnel" my VPN Gateway to the internal VPC to access my Cloud Run Service utilizing VPC Peering?

If so - can someone point me to the documentation that explains this? I found many but can't really extract the exact use-case I mentioned.

Comment: Yes you can achieve that. Do you have errors? issues? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The end result is probably yes, but you are using terms incorrectly or you misunderstand how services are configured. Edit your question with specific details. Cloud Run is not internal to your VPC. VPNs are configured with a static IP address but do not own other static IP addresses. The key is that connection requests are routed, which means there must be a path from source to destination. Add those details.

Comment: Could you please let us know whether your issue has been resolved?

Comment: I can't really mark it as resolved since there was no explicit answers posted that I can "click"

Comment: @xetra11 - If you solved the problem, post your own answer on how you solved it. That way the question does not stay open forever.